# Access-Control-Request-Private-Network header issues

Tags: google-chrome, cors, google-chrome-devtools, preflight, private-network-access

Today we updated the last version of google chrome browser (Version 102.0.5005.61). We have an aplication that runs into a vpn. And since then we start getting this errors on the console:
[image]

As you can see we get a timed out error on the preflight and then the xhr request fails.

We noticed that on this version of chorme they add the new header: Access-Control-Request-Private-Network. An that is what I see on the preflight headers:

[image]

Serching on what could be wrong, since this is happening only when we update the chrome version and in other browsers the site works perfectly; Ive found this:
https://developer.chrome.com/blog/private-network-access-preflight/

On the article is explained what to do and how to handle this.
And show kind of what is happening to me:

> If your request would have triggered a regular CORS preflight without
> Private Network Access rules, then two preflights may appear in the
> network panel, with the first one always appearing to have failed.
> This is a [known bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1290390), and you can safely ignore it.

Based on that I added the new header support on my API that is made on JAVA with spring boot.

```
  response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS");
  response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type");
  response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "180");
  response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network", "true");
  response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition");
```

As you can see just added the header and return 200 for the option request

```
 if ("OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        return;
     }
```

The site is running, meaning it get served and is loaded on chrome browser but all the API calls from the site get that error. (See screen shoots avobe).

But still after that have the same issues. Any one had the same issue and was able to solve?
Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

EDIT:

We just add the headers on the preflight response:
Access-Control-Request-Private-Network: true
Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network: true

Then we go to the google flags configuration and disable this:
[image]

Now Im not sure why google thinks that my requests are insecure.

Comment: As https://developer.chrome.com/blog/private-network-access-preflight/ says, what’s described in the question is a known bug in Chrome versions prior to v100 —  being tracked at https://crbug.com/1290390 — but it doesn’t cause any problems for users, so it can be safely ignored. There are no changes you can make to your own code that will prevent it. And if you’re observing the same problem in a current version of Chrome (v100 later), then I guess that must mean the bug fix in https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/d6d5d01 did not work, and they need to re-fix it.

Comment: HI @sideshowbarker thanks for your answer. Im not worried about the duplicated preflight request. that is a known bug and should not affect. Im worried about the configuration of my site and that is not working on last version of chrome. Do you know if there is anything I should configure to get my site running? Also I have a prev version of chrome and this didnt happen to me. Just with the 102.

Comment: even if the bug "fixed" its totally depends on how chorme segregates private and public. in the [proposed standard](https://wicg.github.io/private-network-access/) you have linked they says it can have false positives and false negatives due to vpn. the best course of actions i believe, you should issue a csp directive to make chrome to treat your app as a public one (dropping any chance to interact other local resources).

Comment: Hi @BagusTesa thanks for your help! Im new at this. How I issue a csp directive?

Comment: `response.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "treat-as-public-address");` havent tried myself as i can't replicate the environment myself. also, you do have the option to just disable pna altogether. that pna header wasn't even in the mdn - which is why other browser works just fine, they havent implemented the proposal yet.

Comment: @BagusTesa If i understand you, you will add that header on the options response and should do the trick?

Comment: Just added the heder like this:      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "180");
      response.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "treat-as-public-address");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition"); and no effect sitill having the timed out.

Comment: sorry, i wasn't clear. no, that csp header is a global one. basically telling the browser: "dont preflight me pna, just treat me as public website." so it had to be served in all response for a good measure.

Comment: As far as _“Do you know if there is anything I should configure to get my site running?”_, the question as currently written doesn’t actually state that your site isn’t running. So the question needs to be updated so that it very clearly explains both what the expected behavior is and what the actual behavior is. Please read through all of https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example — especially the **Describe the problem** part. And copy and paste in the exact wording of any and all error messages the browser is logging in the devtools console.

Comment: @sideshowbarker, well my site is running in fact, Im able to browse the site and it get served by the browser, the problem are the calls that the site made to my API. That on chrome version 102 start getting the timed out. As you mendtioned I have aleredy copy and pasted all the errors in the dev tools. And you can see the errors Ive get. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

This issue is coming for Private and Public combination, like our web is deployed as CloudFront Public URL and backend is Private api hosting, so we are also facing this issue, currently only disabling "Send Private Network Access preflights" property of chrome is working (its only enough).
We have tried setting "preflight request will carry a new header, Access-Control-Request-Private-Network: true, and the response to it must carry a corresponding header, Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network: true" but no luck till now.
Our another web application on which FE/BE both are private hosting is working fine.